# Is it possible to use a DRV8825 to drive higher current stepper motors?

Tags: stepper-motor

I know it's rated to 2.2A per coil, but I need to drive more than double that.  Can additional circuitry be added to this, or does the driver require accurate current sensing?

Answer (score 2):

You will burn out the DRV8825 if you use it to drive higher rated stepper motor.

Majorly, the reason being integrated H bridge and that takes major real estate on the silicon die. So, if you overload it, it might just shutdown due to temperature or over current(RSense).

If you want to actuate a stepper motor larger. I would go with something which has an external H bridge arrangement. Like a stepper indexer.

You can look TI's DRV8711 for this application. It caters these kind of applications and provides more functionality than DRV8825.

Answer (score 1):

A first idea would be to arange extra mosfets at the output but that would lead to nothing since you can only reach the current sensor on the outside and not the CPO ( current overprotection on the inside of the driver). So forget this driver when a higher current is needed.

To overcome this problem TI made the DRV 8711 being a predriver where you can add the output drivers yourself at any current level you need. The predriver needs also the return value of the current sensor.